# Routing between 2 interfaces of a server

Tags: networking, routing

I have two different network interfaces on Ubuntu Server 14.04.5 , eth1 and eth2. Eth1 interface has the ip address is 172.16.0.3/24 with no gateway, the Eth2 interface is assigned for DHCP server with network of 10.10.0.0/24. I want to add a route between the 2 interfaces so that i can connect to the Eth1 from the PC connecting to Eth2. How can i do it? 
Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Enable ip forwarding with command

```
 sudo nano  /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

And change `0` to `1`. Save and exit